# How to make a proxy authentication in headless Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to use a headless Chrome browser through a proxy that requires authentication:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
      args: ["headless", "proxy-server=http://#{host}:#{port}"]
    )
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
```

This works when authentication is not needed, but now I need to use it with authentiation.

In "[List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)" I didn't find how to pass `username` and `password` correctly. In Google I found this option, but it doesn’t work:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
      args: ["headless", "proxy-server=http://#{username}:#{password}@#{host}:#{port}"]
    )
```

How do I use headless-chrome with a proxy authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for solution for almost 2 weeks. It was in 2019 and I haven't even figured it out. As far as I know you can't set proxy with username/password. It was possible before with extension, but now this way is not available. There is a way to do it with [webdrivers](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers#proxy) gem:

If there is a proxy between you and the Internet then you will need to configure the gem to use the proxy. You can do this by calling the configure method.

```rb
Webdrivers.configure do |config|
  config.proxy_addr = 'myproxy_address.com'
  config.proxy_port = '8080'
  config.proxy_user = 'username'
  config.proxy_pass = 'password'
end
```

However I couldn't make it work in my project. The only thing that worked is setting whitelist with my IP on the Proxy server so I do not need to set username/password. So it works without credentials, only like this:

```rb
    Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
      client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
      client.read_timeout = 60
      capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
        'goog:chromeOptions' => { args: %w[no-sandbox headless disable-gpu disable-dev-shm-usage
                                           window-size=1280,1024 enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess] },
        'loggingPrefs' => { browser: 'ALL', client: 'ALL', driver: 'ALL', server: 'ALL' }
      )
      capabilities['goog:chromeOptions'][:args] << "user-agent=#{user_agent}" if user_agent
      capabilities['goog:chromeOptions'][:args] << "proxy-server=http://#{proxy[:ip]}:#{proxy[:port]}" if proxy

      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: capabilities, http_client: client)
    end
```

I know my answer is not you have been looking, but maybe it will help you in some way or push you to correct answer. Good luck

Comment: Thank you! The "Webdrivers" looks like a good solution, but it really doesn't work. Maybe there’s some kind of catch on how to use it. I will try figure it out.